# Modify IFS in bash while building and array

Tags: arrays, bash, ifs

I'm trying to build an array from 4 different arrays in bash with a custom IFS, can you lend me a hand please.

```
#!/bin/bash   
arr1=(1 2 3 4)
arr2=(1 2 3 4)  
arr3=(1 2 3 4)  
arr4=(1 2 3 4)
arr5=()
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=\;
for i in ${!arr1[@]}; do  
    arr5+=($(echo ${arr1[i]} ${arr2[i]} ${arr3[i]} ${arr4[i]}))
done
IFS=$oldIFS
echo ${arr5[@]}
```

i what the output to be:

```
1 1 1 1;2 2 2 2;3 3 3 3;4 4 4 4 4 4
```

But it doesn't work the output is with normal ' '.

```
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Any ideeas?

I tried IFS in different places: 
1) In the for loop
2) Before arr5()

I tested it in the for loop and after IFS does change to ";" but it doesn't take effect in the array creation.

Comment: What is your end goal here? It would be easy to build that string without touching `IFS`.

Comment: yeah i know it's easy just add a ";" after ${arr4[i]}. But i get alot of spaces there and i have to do multiple operation on the string after to split it back in parts where i needit

Comment: also the 4 arrays are variable, so if i get and extra space or some other character in there all the operations after will need to be modified .. Basically i need to trust that the array delimiter will not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IFS` is used during the expansion of `${arr5[*]}`, not while creating `arr5`.

```
arr1=(1 2 3 4)
arr2=(1 2 3 4)  
arr3=(1 2 3 4)  
arr4=(1 2 3 4)
arr5=()
for i in ${!arr1[@]}; do  
    arr5+=("${arr1[i]}" "${arr2[i]}" "${arr3[i]}" "${arr4[i]}")
done
(IFS=";"; echo "${arr5[*]}")
```

Where possible, it's simpler to just change `IFS` in a subshell rather than try to save and restore its value manually. (Your attempt fails in the rare but possible case that `IFS` was unset to begin with.)

That said, if you just want the `;`-delimited string and `arr5` was a way to get there, just build the string directly:

```
for i in ${!arr1[@]}; do
  s+="${arr1[i]} ${arr2[i]} ${arr3[i]} ${arr4[i]};"
done
s=${s%;}  # Remove the last extraneous semicolon
```

Comment: Yep i used ${arr5[@]} instead of ${arr5[*]}. Now works like a charm. The second way has an extra space after ';" and i had to change "; " to ";" . Well now i understand IFS better. Thank you !