# Replace parts of string in filename bash

Tags: bash

I have a list of text files I am reading in like this from a folder `test` like this:

```
file_list="$(ls ~/Desktop/test | 
while read path; do basename "$path"; done)"
```

This will produce a list of these files:

`test_1.txt`
`test_2.txt`

I want to change particular strings in the name, specifically `test` to `this` so the list would then have files like this:

`this_1.txt`
`this_2.txt`

I would like to do this directly in `file_list` I don't want to do it on the actual files in the folder on the computer.

Is looping through one by one the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: For me your first command that generates file_list doesn't work, also, what directory is test?

Comment: It is just a folder on my Desktop, `file_list="$(ls ~/Desktop/test |
while read path; do basename "$path" | cut -f 1 -d '.'; done)"`. I just made a folder there and put some text files in, and it worked for me.  I am just clipping out the extension of .txt too.

Comment: How are you going to have `users/uname` in any of the names when you are processing them through `basename`?  Or when you are generating them in the first place with `ls test`, for that matter?

Comment: That is fair and not important in my end goal, the edit I just made maybe more realistic and easier to reproduce and will solve what I need too

Comment: But it *is* important, because good solutions to your problem could include some that produce the desired result without involving `basename` and `cut`.  We need to understand the context to give you good advice, and what you have presented is inconsistent.

Comment: Or alternatively, if it is not important then please clarify the question by removing the irrelevant parts.

Comment: To full explain the applications I am using and command line utilities will likely confuse the problem more.  I hope I have edited the question so that the irrelevant parts are removed.

Comment: You probably don't need *any* command-line utilties. Something like `file_list=(*); file_list=( "${file_list[@]/#test/this}" )` may be sufficient.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is looping through one by one the most efficient way to [perform substitutions on the filenames]?

No, nor is it the most efficient way to to extract the base names.  Nor, for that matter, is it wise to parse the output of `ls`, though this is a relatively benign case.  If you want to massage a list of filenames then passing the whole list through one `sed` or `awk` process is a better approach.  For example:

```
file_list="$(
  find ~/Desktop/test -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -name '.*' | 
    sed 's,^.*/,,; s,^test,this,'
)"
```

That `find` command outputs paths to the non-dotfiles in the specified directory, one per line, much as `ls` would do.  `sed` then attempts two substitutions on each one: the first removes everything up to and including the last `/` character, ala `basename`, and the second substitutes `this` for `test` where the latter appears at the beginning of what's left of the line.

Note also that this approach, like your original one, will have issues with filenames containing newlines.  It doesn't have an inherent issue with file names containing other whitespace, but you will have trouble interpreting the results correctly if any of the file names contain whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need either loops or external commands (like `basename`, `find`, and `sed`).  Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s nullglob

files=( ~/Desktop/test/* )
bases=( "${files[@]##*/}" )
this_list="${bases[*]//test/this}"

declare -p this_list
```

- `shopt -s nullglob` makes globs expand to nothing when no files match a pattern.  Without it globs expand to (what amounts to) garbage when nothing matches.
- `files=( ~/Desktop/test/* )` populates an array called `files` with the paths to all the files (and directories) in the `~/Desktop/test` directory ( `(~/Desktop/test/test_1.txt ...)` ).  Note that files whose names begin with a dot (`.`) are excluded.  They can be included by running `shopt -s dotglob` earlier in the program.
- `bases=( "${files[@]##*/}" )` populates the `bases` array with the basenames of the files in the `files` array ( `( test_1.txt ... )` ).  See [Parameter expansion [Bash Hackers Wiki]](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) for information about what the `##` is doing.
- If you wanted to remove the `.txt` extensions, as suggested in one of the comments, you could add an extra stage to the process: `stems=( "${bases[@]%.txt}" )`.  It's not possible to do multiple string operations (e.g. `##` and `%`) at once in Bash.
- `this_list="${bases[*]//test/this}"` populates the `this_list` string with all the entries in `bases` with all occurrences of `test` in each of them replaced by `this` ( `"this_1.txt ..."` ).  Again, see [Parameter expansion [Bash Hackers Wiki]](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) for details of how this works.  The entries in the list are separated by spaces.  The entries in the list in the question were separated by newlines.  You can do that for `this_list` by setting `IFS=$'\n'` before doing the `this_list=...` assignment.  See [Modify IFS in bash while building and array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54129969/4154375), [What is the exact meaning of IFS=$'\n'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4128235/4154375), and [Is it a sane approach to "back up" the $IFS variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/264926/264812).  The first character in the value of `IFS` is used to separate array elements when converting an array to a string with `"${arrayname[*]}"`.
- `declare -p this_list` shows the contents of `this_list` in an unambiguous way.

A few general points:

- Never use `ls` in programs.  It's for interactive use only.  You might get away with using it in programs sometimes, but it will eventually bite you hard.  See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [Why *not* parse 'ls' (and what do to instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/264812).
- Avoid putting lists of files in strings.  Use arrays instead.  File paths can contain any character that a string can hold (neither can have have the [NUL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) character).  As a result, there is no safe character, or combination of characters, that can be safely used to separate arbitrary file paths in a string.  The problem can be overcome by quoting the file paths in various ways, but that introduces more problems.
- The "most efficient" way to do this depends on the number of files that need to be processed (among other things).  The code in this answer runs in 0.2s against a directory containing 10 thousand files under Cygwin (which is generally much slower than Linux) on a low-end machine.  That would be good enough for me.  Bash is generally slow though, and the sorting done as part of glob expansion can be very slow when there are huge numbers of files.  If you've got hundreds of thousands of files the pure Bash code might become unusable.  A combination of `find` and `sed` should be able to handle much larger numbers of files, but Bash might struggle to handle the resulting huge strings (or arrays) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Solved here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36795/find-sed-search-and-replace

You can do it one line, using find with -exec and multiple sed commands separated by `;`:

```
find . -exec sed -i '' 's/\([^/.]*\)\..*/\1/g;s?users/uname?gs://uname?g' {} +
```

First sed command up to `s/\([^\.]*\)\..*/\1/g` removes everyting after first `.`

Second sed command `s?users/uname?gs://uname?g` does substitution

Parsing `ls` output is bad practice.